# CSS custom shape

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

please I want to create something like this via CSS.

[image: like this]

Just want to use only CSS to create this custom shape with border radius. Any ideas please?

Comment: @sanna - Welcome to Stack Overflow please read how to ask -  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. This is not a code writing service you must show what you have tried so far

Comment: The image in this post keeps changing...

Comment: @sanaa I think you are confused and dont know what you want ask?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a shape seemed to the shape you need, you have to make some tricks with the borders and transform, also you need use :after and :before selectors to build this kind of shapes.

```css
#diamond-shield {
 width: 0;
 height: 40;
 border: 50px solid transparent;
 border-bottom: 50px solid orange;
 position: relative;
 top: -10px;
    left: 250px;
    transform-origin: 0% 0%;
    transform: rotate(82deg)
}
#diamond-shield:after {
 content: '';
 position: absolute;
 left: -50px; top: 50px;
 width: 0;
 height: 0;
 border: 50px solid transparent;
 border-top: 370px solid orange;
}

#chevron {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 8px;
  top: -9px;
  margin-bottom: 6px;
  left:164px;
  height: 0px;
  width: 60px;
  transform-origin: 0% 0%;
  transform: rotate(-98deg);
}

#chevron:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 51%;
  background: white;
  transform: skew(0deg, 44deg);
}
#chevron:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  background: white;
  transform: skew(0deg, -44deg);
}
```

```html
<div id="diamond-shield"></div>
<div id="chevron"></div>
```

Also you could watch some examples here: https://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/

Comment: Wow, thank you very mach @Pablo Máximo